# org-mode render latex fragments without using cache

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

How do I disable caching behavior when using `C-c C-x C-l` and `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-l`? I want the ability to force `org-mode -> pdfTex` to rerender everything in the current file from scratch.

Here's some more context about what exactly I'm doing and what the motivation is.

I have a setupfile for notes that consists of a whole bunch of LaTeX header lines.

```
#+SETUPFILE: ./setupfile.org
```

Here's a few lines of the setupfile that give a sense of what's in it.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{alphabeta}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{amssymb}
...
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newunicodechar{⊢}{\vdash}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newunicodechar{→}{\rightarrow}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newunicodechar{←}{\leftarrow}
...
```

Whenever I make a new definition or define a new abbreviation, I put it in the shared file. Unfortunately, when I rerender everything (`C-c C-c` and then `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-l`), there's some caching going on and I can't actually see the effects of my change.

Comment: Just delete the images in the sub-folder `ltximg`. I.e., `M-! rm -f ltximg/*`. Afterwards recreate the images with `org-toggle-latex-fragment`.