# org-mode render a particular latex fragment without using cache

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

Is it possible to override the caching behaviour of `org-latex-preview` once and for a particular latex fragment? That is, how should I call the command if I want to regenerate the particular latex fragment at point *without using cache*?

Many times, after introducing a `newcommand` or changing the latex header, I want to regenerate the latex preview of some fragments without using cache, but I do not necessarily want to delete the whole cache or stop using it.

The solution in the general case seems to be to just delete all images in the cache subfolder `ltximg` ([see this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/org-mode-render-latex-fragments-without-using-cache)), but I would still like to be able to just regenerate one image without having to recreate the whole cache.

Comment: You could try [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag). It replaces Org LaTeX preview with AucTeX preview in Org buffers. The LaTeX fragments have a context menu with a menu item for the recompilation of the LaTeX fragment.

Comment: I have been using texfrag after this issue, so I can confirm that is a possibility. Maybe someone can still try to solve the original question for org-latex-preview.

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149119/how-to-regenerate-latex-fragments-in-org-mode) helpful.

Comment: @ayorgo I do not think that answer solves the problem: I do not necessarily want to delete the whole cache every time I want to regenerate a single image.